# What would cause javax.xml.transform.Transformer.transform() to return empty string

Tags: java, xslt

I have a piece of code like this.  I found that `myResults = writer.getBuffer().toString();` returns an EMPTY STRING for some of the use cases but not for the other use cases.

I looked on the server but did not see any special characters in the xml files.  What would 
cause `transformer.transform()` to go wrong so the `myResults = writer.getBuffer().toString();` returns an empty string?  It does not return `null`, just an empty string.

```
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    Result result = new StreamResult(writer);
    try{
        transformer.transform(new StreamSource(theInputStream), result);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    myResults = writer.getBuffer().toString();
```

Thanks a lot,

Comment: And are you sure the source documents actually can be transformed to something based on the xslt ?

Comment: I think it should.  I was able to translate the feed returned for some of the use cases but not the others. How do I validate whether there is anything wrong with the source document? Thanks.

Comment: Try to catch a TransformerException. You could also validate the xml but you need an xsd (schema definition) file to do so. [The Java XML Validation API](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-javaxmlvalidapi/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this recently, but I'm not sure if its the same scenario.

I was developing on windows and deploying onto a linux box.  Everything would transform fine on my windows machine, but on the linux box there where files which would transform, and files which would produce an empty file.  I finally found the answer was in the line endings on the Xslt transforms.  After changing the line endings to Linux style line endings the transforms worked fine.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I observed this behavior when my input XML was invalid. Not its schema, but syntactically incorrect. It contained `<!-- -- -->`. `--` is not valid inside an XML comment.